# Multiple links in one question: Quick-List

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486346/new-lines-and-tabs-in-json-decode-php-7) about `php7` and `json` and it occurred to me: **would a question with multiple php7-migration related problems be suitable for SO?** If more problems appear, more questions would be generated and the question-index would grow. This could be done with any other thing that is mainly related.

To make it clear, the question-type I'm asking about can be found more frequently on those forums where there are quick-lists that point to other posts. Something like an **index** that gathers other stand-alone tutorials to make it easier for people to find what they need about that subject.

*Do you have an example, please?*

**Sure:** [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them). This question has a bunch of links, maybe to itself, maybe to another question, but it has a bunch of them. If you take it to the douche level, this would not be considered a real question, it would probably be flagged or require editing (maybe not, who am I to tell xD).

Anyways, this type of question I find helpful, but why don't we (by 'we', I mean 'I') see more of these out there? **Are they discouraged?** If so, **what's so bad about them?** If not, **should people start 'asking' them?**

---

*I'm afraid that people might do it anyway, but please, don't come with comments like `You have tags for that, don't you?`*.

Comment: Seem you are speaking of a well-curated tag-wiki...